# cant get my cloud function to connect to sql instance?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

im new with the google cloud platform and i've been trying to learn about google functions and other things that work with it. i read that you can make your function connect to your cloud sql instance, so i tried to do a test function to do it, following the oficial documentation, but it always gives me an error when i try to deploy it.

im using node.js for the function (but if you guys have working examples in any other languages i'd love to see them as well) and postgresql for my cloudsql.

below is the code of the function.

```
const Knex = require('knex');

// createUnixSocketPool initializes a Unix socket connection pool for
// a Cloud SQL instance of Postgres.
const createUnixSocketPool = async config => {
  // Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
  // secure - consider a more secure solution such as
  // Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
  // keep secrets safe.
  return Knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      user: 'here i put instance user i made', // e.g. 'my-user'
      password: 'the user password', // e.g. 'my-user-password'
      database: 'the db i made', // e.g. 'my-database'
      host: '/cloudsql/projectname:southamerica-east1:instancename', // e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'
    },
    // ... Specify additional properties here.
    ...config,
  });
};
```

literaly copied and pasted from the documentation with the little changes they said to do and it doesn't work... i couldn't really understand well what the unix socket thing is about, should i have created something else before setting up the function? any idea what might be going wrong? this is the error message i get:

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**Set up a Cloud SQL instance**

- Enable the Cloud SQL Admin API in the project you are connecting from, if you haven't already done so:
  [Enable the API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https://console.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.74909269.632056444.1668708964-1011620526.1656024860&_gac=1.25140680.1667947085.Cj0KCQiAmaibBhCAARIsAKUlaKRbWaOsUcMxtGRYSZrsGbwOof2EQD-I9-6ATYKSr8qq73SEjpMOhawaAnDWEALw_wcB)
- [Create a Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-instance).
  By default, Cloud SQL assigns a public IP address to a new instance. You also have the option to assign a private IP address. For more information about the connectivity options for both, see the [Connecting Overview](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview) page.

You can check this document to [Configure Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#configure).

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-cloud-functions